# How do I find out what user my ASP.Net MVC application is running as?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, iis

I want to display the windows user that the application is running as on a diagnostics page on my ASP.Net MVC database check page to help the user check whether they've setup their IIS correctly.  Where can I find that information?

I tried System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name but that appears to contain the logged in user by forms authentication, not the underlying windows user that the code is running as.

Comment: I see you're trying to make your own diagnostics page. If I simply wanted to check, i.e. using IIS or something, [is this related?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15565826/what-windows-account-does-an-asp-net-4-application-run-under)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

Comment: System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name

Answer (score 3):

You can use `System.Environment.UserName` to get the windows user account that the application is running as.

Comment: +1 since that's another option.  It appears that it doesn't append the domain but it's probably useful in some situations.